# Executing powershell in a working directory containing angle brackets

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

Say I have two files in a directory with angle brackets in the path (e.g. `c:\foo[bar]`)

- `test.ps1`
- `test.bat`

In `test.ps1` all I have is:

```
"HelloWorld"
```

In `test.bat` I have:

```
powershell -file test.ps1
echo %errorlevel%
```

Where powershell v2 is installed, if I execute `test.bat` from the command prompt, with the working directory in the `foo[bar]`, I get "HelloWorld" output from the ps script but the error code **1** echoed to the console. This does not occur when the path contains no angle brackets or in instances where powershell v3 is installed ("HelloWorld" is output and **0** is returned as the error code).

This just appears to be a problem when using the powershell v2 executable with the `-file` switch. My first assumption is that this is a bug, but I couldn't find anything out there on this specific problem.

Is there any workaround or solution to this?

Comment: Actually I think you're running into a bug of V3 that is causing the exit code to always be 0.  See https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/750653/powershell-exe-doesn-t-return-correct-exit-codes-when-using-the-file-option  The workaround is to use the -command parameter instead of -file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have the script itself specify its exit code. I would start by having a read of this: http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script but the top comment from Keith Hill is probably more specific to your case.

Comment: Actually this solves the problem for both v2 and v3. If I explicitly end the script with `exit 0` then I get the right error code in the bat file. Thanks!